# Symfony2 How is formBuilder function called?

Tags: symfony, function-calls

Hi I am new to symfony2 and while I was reading the documentation I could not figure out how

`public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)` is called from within the TaskType class (in the example) using the helper createForm() in the controller.

I looked into the FormFactory.php file and I could see how the function getName() is called but nowhere the buildForm().

I know it is not really important in order to code a form but I would like to know so as to get a better grasp of what I am doing and why.

Thanks,
idipous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In Symfony2.0

Around line 280 in `\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory` there is the line:

```
$type->buildForm($builder, $options);
```

and a little lower is:

```
$typeExtension->buildForm($builder, $options);
```

#### In Symfony2.1

Around line 124 `\Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType` in function createBuilder:

```
$this->buildForm($builder, $options);
```

and a number of other places in this file.

This is used in `\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory` on line 165 in function addType:

```
$this->registry->addType($this->resolvedTypeFactory->createResolvedType(
        $type,
        array(),
        $parentType ? $this->registry->getType($parentType) : null
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks Luke. I wonder how I missed that. Well now it is clear.